# How do I change a particular part of a XML which has been read into Python and then create a new XML with this change?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, elementtree

So I am using BeautifulSoup to read and parse an XML below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
with open(r"....TestXML.xml", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
bs_data = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
```

Within my XML I have line which states:

```
<Increase="0">1.75</Increase>
```

I would like to change `1.75` in this line to a 2.5 and create a new XML with the zero but I am not sure how to go about this.

The code

```
b_unique = bs_data.find_all('Increase') 
print(b_unique)
```

Helps me to find the line but I do not know how to change the `1.75` within the line.

If you know how to do this by either beautifulsoup or element tree please feel free to share

Comment: You can find a solution [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: what did you try? BS should have functions to replace `inner text` in tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below example,  firstly,grab the targeted element(increase) using
beautifulsoup object then modify its content and save it to a new file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(r"....TestXML.xml", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")

element = bs.find("Increase")

element.string = "2.5"

new_xml_filename = "modified_test.xml"
with open(new_xml_filename, 'w') as new_file:
    new_file.write(str(bs))
```